# What it's wrong in translation function?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I tried to create and translate a polygon in openGL, I create a function for translation but this create a white line from x0 to v_size and I don't understand why ?

This is my function for polygon translation

```
public void translate1(GL2 gl, double x0, double x1, double y0, double y1){
    double step = 0.2;
    for(double i = 0; i < v_size; i += step){
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

            gl.glVertex2d(x0 + i, y0);
            gl.glVertex2d(x0 + i, y1);
            gl.glVertex2d(x1 + i, y1);
            gl.glVertex2d(x1 + i, y0);

        gl.glEnd();
    }
}
```

Initial x0 = 0, x1 = 10, y0 = 20, y1 = 30.

Thanks !
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is, that you draw squares every step units away from each other. Since nothing gets cleared in the meantime, the overlapping quads form a line.

It is rather unclear what you are trying to achieve. A translation would usually not draw multiple quads. If you are trying to do an animation, then you'll have to split the movement over multiple frames and draw exactly one square in every frame.